# Entity Framework Child & Parent (List Property)

Tags: sql-server, ajax, vb.net, web-services, entity-framework-5

I'm working on a project with EF5, Vb.net, AJAX (Javascript), ASMX-Webservices and HTML.

My question is if i have (example classes):

```
Public Class Company

Public Property CompanyId As Integer

Public Property Name As String

Public Overridable Property Companytype As Companytype

End Class
```

and the Class:

```
Public Class Companytype

Public Property CompanytypeId As Integer

Public Property Name As String

-> Public Overridable Property Companies As List(Of Company)

End Class
```

do I need the -> marked line?

I'm afraid but I really don't know which advance this line brings to me.
Actually I can read all the Companies of a Companytype like this:

```
Public Shared Function PostCompanyTypeCompanies() As List(Of Company)
    Dim db As New Context
    Dim x As Integer = 1
    Dim y = (From c In db.Companies Where c.CompanyType.CompanyTypeId = x Select New With _
                                                                                 {c.Name, _
                                                                                  c.CompanyType})
    Dim z As List(Of Company) = y.AsEnumerable() _
                                .Select(Function(t) New Company With _
                                    {.Name = t.Name, _
                                     .CompanyType = t.CompanyType}).ToList()
    Return z
End Function
```

This with 'x' is just an example, I can just pass the CompanytypeId to the function.
The problem with the lists is, I always get a circular reference when I want to get the Companytypes for a new Company and I can't access the companytype of a Company like:

```
 Company.Companytype.Name
```

When I do it without the list everything works fine, because i can store the whole Companytpe to the Company.

I  tried the other possibility with setting the Getter of the Child & Parent Properties to Protected then the problem was logically also that I couldn't access the variable as I described a 3 lines above.

So the important question is: Is this -> List Property mandatory?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do I need the -> marked line?` NO. It is redundant information (with no real use), which potentially, might provoke consistency errors. Example:

```
Dim company1 As New Company()
Dim listCompanies As New List(Of Company)()

Dim companiesType1 As New Companytype()
listCompanies.Add(company1)

With companiesType1
    .CompanytypeId = 1
    .Name = "Type 1"
    .Companies = listCompanies
End With

With company1
    .CompanyId = 1
    .Name = "1"
    .Companytype = companiesType1
End With
```

The code above defines `Company1` and the associated type (`companiesType1`... although we have the problem of "first the egg or the chicken", what gives a first idea of why the chosen approach is erroneous). If you create a new company of the same type:

```
Dim company2 As New Company()
With company2
    .CompanyId = 2
    .Name = "2"
    .Companytype = companiesType1
End With
```

You would have to redefine `companiesType1` (update its `Companies` property), to keep the consistency. But, as far as this is redundant information, `Companytype` would "do the job" independently upon this fact:

```
If (company2.Companytype Is company1.Companytype) Then
    'Both companies have the same type
End If
```

The aforementioned condition will always be true: either if `companiesType1` contains the right information (was updated with `company2`) or not.

If you need to have a list of all the companies belonging to certain type, you should better rely on a different class storing all the values (e.g., `allTheCompanies`).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, now I can leave it away without any troubles!